# How Can I draw circle with arc

Tags: html, canvas

I drawn 200 or more(highly fluid) object in canvas used by rectangle.

like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/o5xp21t2/

```
    ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(s.x1,s.y1);
        ctx.lineTo(s.x2,s.y2); 
        ctx.lineTo(s.x3,s.y3); 
        ctx.lineTo(s.x4,s.y4); 
        ctx.lineTo(s.x1,s.y1);
        if(draw){
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.fillStyle="blue";
            ctx.fillText(k,(s.x2+s.x3)/2,(s.y2+s.y3)/2);    
        }
```

....

but, I wann to draw circle with arc

like this -> [image]

how can I change the source...

here is my position data...

whole length : 156356

start   end     length(end-start)

488     1546        1058        
2082        3590        1508        
5246        6369        1123        
8591        8773        182     
9185        9292        107     
11367       12887       1520        
12943       14224       1281        
14604       14846       242     
15960       16700       740     
16945       17652       707     
17868       22028       4160        
22194       25021       2827        
25030       28242       3212        
30002       30088       86      
30966       31064       98      
34894       35952       1058        
35903       37324       1421        
37970       38155       185     
38921       39220       299     
39347       41548       2201        
41577       43826       2249        
44541       46511       1970        
47664       48266       602     
50877       51350       473     
51456       52133       677     
52185       52544       359     
54692       55090       398     
55090       56583       1493        
57343       58791       1448        
59447       60955       1508        
61653       61760       107     
62176       62727       551     
63056       63742       686     
63948       64907       959     
65920       66039       119     
66175       66288       113     
66314       66430       116     
66443       66691       248     
67865       67957       92      
68113       68223       110     
69020       69148       128     
69597       69794       197     
69964       70266       302     
70515       70898       383     
71680       99829       28149       
71955       73948       1993        
74382       75899       1517        
76112       76219       107     
76311       76439       128     
76524       76760       236     
76895       78323       1428        
78501       79734       1233        
79907       80911       1004        
80989       81402       413     
81515       81625       110     
81744       81974       230     
82098       82499       401     
82694       83059       365     
83198       84548       1350        
84707       85360       653     
85348       85827       479     
85904       86179       275     
86236       87717       1481        
87739       88017       278     
88350       94631       6281        
96010       98217       2207        
98518       98982       464     
110555      112240      1685        
112161      114377      2216        
115597      115761      164     
116742      117701      959     
117928      119427      1499        
119549      119791      242     
120043      120345      302     
120567      121094      527     
121480      121977      497     
122063      124180      2117        
124185      125363      1178        
125459      125728      269     
126126      131822      5696        
143395      143859      464     
144160      146367      2207        
147746      154027      6281        
154360      154638      278     
154660      156141      1481

Answer (score 1):

**Stroke a series of arcs around a centerpoint.**

To get variable length arcs that correspond to data values:

- Calculate the total of the data values,
- A full circle is PI*2 so each arc's angle is: (PI*2) * thisValue / totalValues

[image]

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

var values=[];
var totalValues=0;

for(var i=0;i<15;i++){
  d=parseInt(Math.random()*20-10);
  values.push(d);
  totalValues+=Math.abs(d);
}

var PI2=Math.PI*2;
var cx=125;
var cy=125;
var radius=100;
var gap=PI2/160;
var accumAngle=0;

ctx.lineWidth=2;
ctx.strokeStyle='black';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(cx,cy,radius,0,PI2);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();

ctx.lineWidth=12;
for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++){
  var v=values[i];
  var r=(v<0)?-6:6;
  var a=(PI2-gap*values.length)*Math.abs(v)/totalValues;

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(cx,cy,radius+r,accumAngle,accumAngle+a);
  ctx.strokeStyle=randomColor();
  ctx.stroke();

  accumAngle+=gap+a;

  ctx.fillStyle=ctx.strokeStyle;
  ctx.fillRect(270,i*23+5,10,15);
  ctx.fillStyle='black';
  ctx.fillText('Value#'+i+'= '+v,285,i*23+15);
}

function randomColor(){ 
  return('#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16));
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<h4>Arc lengths correspond to data values<br>Negative values are inside the circle<br>Positive values are outside the circle</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=350 height=360></canvas>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LELt.png)

Comment: thanks. but.. each arc were difference length. for example.. http://openi.nlm.nih.gov/imgs/512/37/3228488/3228488_gbeevr102f01_3c.png

Comment: Ahhhhhh...NOW you add that information! Well, you'll have to size your arcs in proportion to the size of your data. Calculate the total sum of your data values (totalDataValue). The total angle of a circle is PI*2.  Therefore, you can calculate the sweeping angle of each arc like this: var thisArcsAngle = (PI*2) * thisDataValue/totalDataValue. Each data related arc you add will start at the angle where the previous arc ended (plus a gap angle) and will end at the starting angle + thisArcAngle.

Comment: It's nearly 2am here where I am, so the example source is up to you to write--I'm going to bed!  Just follow the instructions I left in my comment and you'll be fine.  Good luck with your project :-)

Comment: sorry... I failed.. may I send my source to you?

Comment: and one more question.... how can I write not overlapping label.. like aboved Example... (http://openi.nlm.nih.gov/imgs/512/37/3228488/3228488_gbeevr102f01_3c.png)

Comment: Edit your question and post your current code...I'll take a look.

Comment: I re-upload... thank.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25965132/html5how-can-i-draw-circle-with-arc

Comment: thanks... but.. gap was not fixed.. each object had start, end positon. and whole length fixed(ost = orf_start[k];oen = orf_end[k];).. I think.. each object length must division by whole length...

Comment: The gap is a fixed angle (PI*2/160). The total required gap angle is subtracted from PI*2 and only the remainder is used to proportionally draw the arcs based on the sum value of the data. If a data value==0 then a 'double gap' will appear because the zero data value means a zero arc (no arc--just a gap). Feel free to adjust the code if your design requirements are different. Good luck with your project.

Comment: I upload my position data this queustion..(modify this).. please see above... thanks..

Comment: Just plug in your 'length' data into the `values` array. Goodnight!

Comment: it use not start, end position.. so all component has same gap.. I want this image.. http://previews.figshare.com/690949/preview_690949.png (It has difference gap by start, end position)

Comment: **I have taught you all the tools you need to create your desired results.** The width of the color arcs and the width of the gaps in between are both controlled using a percentage of PI*2 to create the desired arc angle sweep.  Take these tools I have taught you and refine the code to create your desired design.

Comment: That's off-topic to your question, but check out context.fillText("Hello",20,40) with x=cx+radius*Math.cos(angle); y=cy+radius*Math.sin(angle);